# Flutter: creating a List<Widget> with two array (loop)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this two arrays and want to generate Column Widget like below.

```
class ProfileWidget extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<FaIcon> infoIcon = [
      FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.idCard),
      FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.at),
    ];

    List infoText = [
      'AAA',
      'A@A.com',
    ];

    return Column(
      children: [
        // divider box
        Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Divider(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    height: 40,
                    thickness: 2,
                    indent: 30,
                    endIndent: 10,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Info",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.lightGreen, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Divider(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    height: 40,
                    indent: 10,
                    endIndent: 30,
                    thickness: 2,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        List<Widget>.generate(infoIcon.length, (index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 120,
                  child: Center(
                    child: FaIcon(
                      infoIcon[index],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 175,
                  child: Text(
                    infoText[index],
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: notNotDefaultStyle,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        }),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I get an error like

`The element type 'List<Widget>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'`

So, I changed to `dynamic` and then I also receive Generates a list of values. Creates a list with [length] positions and fills it with values created by calling [generator] for each index in the range 0 .. length - 1 in increasing order.

I even delete <> but then, still it does not work. How can I generate widgets with two arrays using `List.generate()` in flutter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Column(
   children: List<Widget>.generate(infoIcon.length, (index) {
      return Container(
         child: Text('${infoText[index]}') 
      );
    },
  )
)
```

Comment: ` (new) List<Widget> List.generate(int length, Widget Function(int) generator, {bool growable = true})
dart:core

Generates a list of values.

Creates a list with [length] positions and fills it with values created by calling [generator] for each index in the range 0 .. length - 1 in increasing order.

List<int>.generate(3, (int index) => index * index); // [0, 1, 4]
The created list is fixed-length if [growable] is set to false.

The [length] must be non-negative.

The element type 'List<Widget>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'` I still get this error

Comment: Use "List<Widget>.generate" inside a Column.

Comment: It is inside the column?

Comment: Did you review the sample code I shared? Create a "column" after your divider box and put "list generator" inside it's children field. "list generator" not return a widget, it return a widget list. You can not put "widget list" inside a field waiting for a widget.

Comment: I just did but now I am getting `The element type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'` this error? tried using `List<Widget>` and other stuffs as wel.

Comment: I needed to add `...` in front of the `List<Wdget>`! but thank you so much thouh